# How to install the magento patch and steps to steps

Tags: magento-1.7

Important: New Magento Security Patch - Install it Now
Urgent: Immediately install Magento critical security patches
Second Reminder: Download and install Magento critical security patches now.
Critical Reminder: Download and install Magento security patches. Download now.

After the installation in patches, its affect a site or not ? please share
then this patches are mandatory or not ? please help me ,am helpless

Answer (score 1):

Its mandatory to install security patches. Otherwise your site is open for others expecially SUPEE 5344.

to install, go to doc root, type sh patchname.sh. Then the message will show as patch has applied successfully. The messages will show in admin even if you have installed patches. To remove, please follow the steps written by my buddy Amit Bera.

To check the patches installed successfully, go to http://magento.com/security-patch and https://shoplift.byte.nl/

If you donot installed till now, go and fix before its become too late. Good luck mate.

Comment: Thank you So much.."SAFE: This site appears to be safe." this message to show ..now no problem ?

Comment: yes. you are good to go.. please accept this if this helped. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There have no process to disable the message after install ssh file.So you need to disable message manually.

Just go `admin>System>notification Urgent: Immediately install Magento critical security patches make Make   as read`.